# Why the same code when running on device below 5s will throw an error

Tags: ios, unrecognized-selector

The code works well when it runs on iPhone5s+, but when test in iPhone4s and iPhone5, it will crash and say "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

The error message showed like this. And in xcdatamodeld file, I set the property 'Day' to be Interger 64, so maybe that's the reason why it cannot run below 5s+. It's irrelevant with the system version, because I test in different simulator with the same version.

And seems there are already the same question be asked, the solution is change the 'Day' property from NSInterger to NSNumber.

[image]

Comment: **HOW** are we supposed to help without a single line of code? What is your code? What is the error message? Are the iOS version the same?

Comment: You need to show us the code that is failing. You also need to tell us which OS build you are testing on for each device., and provide the full error message, the stack trace, and show which source line is failing. As meda says in his answer, it's most likely an issue with the OS version rather than the device model, but we can't be sure unless you provide a LOT more info.

Answer (score 1):

It is not about the device model, it is more about the `iOS` version.

If you used a method available only in a newer SDK, it will crash on older version with that error.

To avoid such crash you need to check if it responds to selector using [`- respondsToSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:)

example:

```
if( [MySuperclass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aMethod)] ) {
    // invoke the inherited method
    [super aMethod];
}
```

If you want to support multiple ios version,  you must check for selectors that are only available in new SDK version

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You helped me to get a new skill to test the method availability among different iOS versions.